# How can I make a term in an equation bigger

Tags: math-mode, equations

In mathoverflow, I have the following Latex code:

```
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (1+\frac{3i}{n})e^{2(1+\frac{3i}{n})}(\frac{3}{n})$$
```

[image]

That is a screenshot of the result. Right now I can't really see the exponent on the `e^2` term.
How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, but this is off-topic as it is about MathJax which is not related to TeX or LaTeX, even though it supports a subset of the syntax.

Comment: Oh is it? Alright ..

Comment: @cfr - I believe the OP's question isn't so much about MathJax in general as it is about the concern that "right now I can't really see the exponenet on the `e^2` [term]". As such, I'd say the question does fall in the scope of this site.

Comment: You can use the code: `e^{2(1+\tfrac{3t}{n})}`which yields $ e^{2(1+\tfrac{3t}n)} $.

Comment: The exponent is visible; of course typing `\exp\Bigl(2\Bigl(1+\frac{3i}{n}\Bigr)\Bigr)` would make the formula clearer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it casn be solved by egreg comment.

Comment: Its not off topic and it is marked sovled?

Comment: @Mico Before you edited it out, the question was, does mathoverflow allow the loading of packages to customise the formatting of equations? That is surely MathJax. I assume the OP knows that LaTeX allows `\usepackage{}`.

Comment: @cfr - The OP's original query was indeed phrased somewhat suboptimally. It did have all the hallmarks of an X-Y question, for sure. However, I think it was reasonably clear that the OP's main objective was never really about learning about packages for MathJax; instead, it was about how to make the material in the argument of `e^{...}` more readable. Anyway, there really isn't a useful package to enlarge this material. Instead, what should be done is to employ `\exp(...)` notation. That's why I chose to edit the OP's query (possibly a bit too severely...) and to post an answer.

Comment: @Zarko - Just for the record: I posted my answer only a few seconds after egreg posted his comment.

Comment: Dear @Mico, I'm very sorry, but I didn't see your answer in time. Anyway, +1 for it.

Comment: @Mico I just meant that it seemed clearly off-topic when I voted to close it on those grounds. I'm glad you could edit it to be on topic - that honestly didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the material in the exponent of `e^{...}` is too small for easy reading, don't use `e^{...}` notation. Instead, use `\exp(...)` notation. By the way, the size of the material in the exponent should not be the only typographic concern; you also need to do something to enlarge the parentheses suitably.

The following answer shows first your original solution, then one that uses `\tfrac` ("text-style fraction") and `\big` parentheses, finally a solution that uses `\frac` and `\Big` parentheses.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for `\tfrac` macro
\begin{document}
\[
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (1+\frac{3i}{n})e^{2(1+\frac{3i}{n})}(\frac{3}{n})
\]

\[
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bigl(1+\tfrac{3i}{n}\bigr) \exp\bigl(2\bigl(1+\tfrac{3i}{n}\bigr)\bigr) \bigl(\tfrac{3}{n}\bigr)
\]

\[
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Bigl(1+\frac{3i}{n}\Bigr) \exp\Bigl(2\Bigl(1+\frac{3i}{n}\Bigr)\!\Bigr) \Bigl(\frac{3}{n}\Bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps the parenthesis that immediately follows `\exp` (and the correpsonding closing one, of course) should be `\bigg` instead?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti - I'd say it's a close call between `\Big` and `\bigg`. Actually, either one is OK. I suspect, though, that @egreg would prefer `\Big`. :-)